# Get value of k8s service connection in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server

We have many k8s service connections in our Azure DevOps that contains KubeConfig:

[image]

When I edit a connection I can't see the existing KubeConfig value.

Is there a way to find the existing value? (I searched for rest api but couldn't find something useful).

BTW - we are using Azure DevOps **Server** 2020, so I can access the DB if needed.

Comment: Why do you need to view the content of KubeConfig?

Comment: As a matter of fact it does not, It just seemed strange to me.

Comment: I want to compare the config there to the config that exists elsewhere.